# how to stop and restart C++ code running from python with ctypes

Tags: python, c++, ctypes

I have a C++ code that I run and use it's functions from Python. My question is - how do I stop that code from running (like ctrl+c if it was in console) and then restart, but only the c++ part, the rest of python should work as before.

Here is how I use the c++ code:

```
from os.path import abspath, dirname, join
fname = abspath(inspect.getfile(inspect.currentframe()))
lib = ctypes.cdll.LoadLibrary(join(dirname(fname), 'shared_lib.so'))
func = lib.func
func.restype = None
func.argtypes= None
```

Is there a way to re-do it?

Answer (score 0):

You could add a signal handler:

```
import signal
from os.path import abspath, dirname, join

def restart_server():
    # Restart code

signal.signal(signal.SIGTERM, restart_server)
fname = abspath(inspect.getfile(inspect.currentframe()))
lib = ctypes.cdll.LoadLibrary(join(dirname(fname), 'shared_lib.so'))
func = lib.func
func.restype = None
func.argtypes= None
```

This signal handler catches the signal TERMINATE (Ctrl+C) and calls the given function.